# insert null value for auto incremented primary key

Tags: postgresql, aws-glue

I'm using aws glue and i'm trying to insert (in pg databases) line with null value in primary key. I get this error :

```
An error occurred while calling o204.pyWriteDynamicFrame. ERROR: null value in column "abc" violates not-null constraint.
```

The issue is that primary key has a sequence
nextval('abc'::regclass).

Is it a parameter in glue to avoid this error ? Thanks

Conf :
AWS GLUE,
Python job,
Postgres databases

Comment: This is by design. You cannot have a null value as primary key. Sequence is irrelevant.

Comment: Thanks user_0, i found solution to drop null value in my dynamicframe ;)